# How Can I Do Peach Math Number Switcher Program Like This?

Tags: python, list, math, numbers

Here's The Program I Want To Do.
[Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JckU1.jpg)

[x,y,z]

X = The Largest Number Of Position X, By Start From Number Zero

Y = The Largest Number Of Position Y, By Start From Number Zero

Z = The Largest Number Of Position Z, By Start From Number Zero

C = The Sum Number Of Position (x, y, z), It Must Not Equal To C.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the range() function in nested loops to get your number combinations and pick the ones that meet your criteria:

```
X = 1
Y = 1
Z = 2
C = 3

result = []
for x in range(X+1):
    for y in range(Y+1):
        for z in range(Z+1):
            if x+y+z != C:
                result.append([x,y,z])

print(result)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2]]
```

The number combinations could also be obtained using the product function from itertools.  This would allow you to get the result in a list comprehension:

```
X = 1
Y = 1
Z = 2
C = 3

from itertools import product

result = [ p for p in product(*map(range,(X+1,Y+1,Z+1))) if sum(p) != C]

print(result)
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), 
 (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 2)]
```

An additional way to do this is to unrank the combinations in a single loop:

```
X = 1
Y = 1
Z = 2
C = 3

result = []
for n in range((X+1)*(Y+1)*(Z+1)):
    n,z = divmod(n,Z+1)
    x,y = divmod(n,Y+1)
    if x+y+z != C:
        result.append([x,y,z])

print(result)
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], 
 [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
X = int(input("X:"))
Y = int(input("Y:"))
Z = int(input("Z:"))
C = int(input("C:"))
array = []

def add_one(max_array):
    for i in range(max_array[0]+1):
        if len(max_array) != 1:
            for j in add_one(max_array[1:]):
                yield [i] + j
        else:
            yield [i]

for i in add_one([X,Y,Z]):
    if sum(i) == C:
        continue
    array.append(i)

print(array)

#input
X:1
Y:1
Z:2
C:3
#output
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 2]]

#input
X:0
Y:2
Z:1
C:2
#output
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).